# How to make the font of an HTML button bigger with CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, excel

I am trying to create a question mark button with no background color and a black font border but, despite on what I am writing on the font-size the button does not become bigger can someone help me on how I can achieve that? Also onclick I would like the button to have a textbox with a definition if you could give me an insight of how to do that too it would be perfect I am assuming JavaScript. Thank you! :)

```css
.btn{
    background-color:rgba(252, 252, 252,0);
    border: 0 none;
    color:rgb(0,164,224);
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 60;
    size: 300px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;}
```

```html
 html:

<button class="btn" id="button?">?</button>
```

Comment: You should use `font-size: 60%` or `font-size: 60px`. You can also use for example rem, em, vh, vw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add  `px`.

```css
.btn{
    background-color:rgba(252, 252, 252,0);
    border: 0 none;
    color:rgb(0,164,224);
    font-weight: 800px;
    font-size: 60px;
    size: 300px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;}
```

```html
html:

<button class="btn" id="button?">?</button>
```